# Convert Qt QByteArray to OpenCV cv::InputArray

Tags: qt, opencv, qt4, qt5

How can I convert a Qt QByteArray to a cv::InputArray?

I need to pass in a custom feature vector:

```
// Constructor
HoGDetector::HoGDetector(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

    qDebug() << "Creating HoG Detector";

    // Set the SVM Detector ( Default OpenCV One )
    m_HoG.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

    // Read
    QFile svmVectorFile(":/descriptorvector.dat");
    QByteArray svmVector = svmVectorFile.readAll();

    // Set the SVM Detector - custom trained HoG Detector
    m_HoG.setSVMDetector(svmVector);

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV knows how to convert a std:vector to an InputArray, so this should do the trick:

```
m_HoG.setSVMDetector(std::vector<uchar>(svmVector.begin(), svmVector.end()));
```